# Как передать параметр "номер позиции", элемента listview, в массив

Tags: java, android, listview

По нажатию на элемент `listview` нужно передать значение позиции в массив без дополнительных циклов

```
    public class TicketActivity extends Activity {
//...
for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
    int[] arrayAnswer = new int[20];
    //...    
    ArrayAdapter < String > adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listNumber1);
    listAnswers.setAdapter(adapter1);
    listAnswers.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {@
        Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //нужно при каждом проходе цикла запихнуть значение position в массив arrayAnswer 
        }
    });
```

Comment: у вас 20 `ListView`?

Comment: Вам надо код подрефакторить.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте `arrayAnswer` полем активити и пишите туда из `onItemClick()`.

Большего из Вашего кода не понять, к сожалению.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как можно использовать переменную `position` вне `onItemClick()`

Comment: Есть такое понятие, как поле видимости. Так что саму переменную никак нельзя. А вот ее значение можно сохранять в переменные с бОльшим полем видимости, если надо. В поля класса, хоть в глобальные статические. Вопрос только, а действительно без этого никак?